# How do I get imports from another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have two python scripts in C:\Python.

Rather than have

Script 1.py

```
Import csv
import scipy
print('i')
```

Script 2.py

```
Import csv
import scipy
print('k')
```

How do I have:

Script 1.py

```
Import csv
import scipy
print('i')
```

Script 2.py

```
#read imports from Script 1.py
print('k')
```

I would rather not have to rely on cmd.

Comment: from fileName import className/functionName/*

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM Could you show example?

Comment: Sure, see my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

In general I think this is not good practice, but if you really don't want to specify the imports again, you could do this in script2:

```
import script1

with open("some.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = script1.csv.reader(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make it simple, you have two file a.py and b.py

contents of a.py is this,

```
def greet():
    print("Hello")
```

Now we want to import the greet function in b.py

so b.py will be like this,

```
from a import greet

greet()
```

will give me this output:

> Hello

This will work similar for classes,
**a.py**

```
class Hello:
    def greet(self):
        print("Hello")
```

Then you could import the class in b.py like this,

```
from a import Hello

Hello().greet()
```

which will give you the same results.

you could use comma "," to import multiple classes and functions,

so here is a.py

```
class Hello:
    def greet(self):
        print("Hello")

class Bye:
    def greet(self):
        print("Bye")
```

and b.py would be

```
from a import Hello, Bye

Hello().greet()
Bye().greet()
```

or you can just use a wild card like this,

```
from a import *

Hello().greet()
Bye().greet()
```